# How to display content assigned to foreignkey DJango

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want to display content assigned to foreignkey. After clicking on user name display in new page all of his content. Something like in "/users/" display every users but after clicking on name go to "/users/1".

```
class Users(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    image = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=600)
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=80)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "User"
        verbose_name_plural = "Users"

class Content(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=80)
    image = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=600)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(Ekipa, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='User')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Content"
        verbose_name_plural = "Content"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this part of your question:

```
 After clicking on user name display in new page all of his content.
 Something like in "/users/" display every users but after clicking on 
 name go to "/users/1".
```

you can proceed like this:

in views:

```
def user_list(request):
  users = Users.objects.all()
  context = {'users': users}
  return render(request, 'users_list.html', context)

def user_detail(request, id):
  user = Users.objects.get(id=id)
  context = {'user': user}
  return render(request, 'user_detail.html', context)
```

in urls:

```
path('users/', user_list, name='user_list'),
path('users/<str:id>/', user_detail, name='user_detail'),
```

in users_list.html:

```
{% for user in users %}
   <a href="{%url 'user_detail' user.id%}">{{user.name}}</a><br>
{% endfor %}
```

in user_detail.html:

```
{{user.email}}
<img src="{{user.image.url}}" alt="">
{{user.description}}
```